# How do you say "I knew I should have gone"?

Tags: concordance-des-temps

Instinctively, it should be « Je savais que j’aurais dû y aller » but according to [this website](https://www.connectigramme.com/concordance.html/odyframe.htm), this isn't a possibility.

Even in English however, the rules make sense: "I knew that he was coming" is the correct concordance des temps, and "I knew I should have gone" is also correct, so is this phrase not an example of the c.d.t, or is it elsewhere on the site?

[image]

Comment: Your sentence in French looks correct to me

Comment: I should have went is incorrect : https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378464/should-have-went-vs-should-have-gone

Comment: Please quote what in "this website" implies your translation wouldn't be a possibility.

Comment: @jlliagre I'm not sure, but doesn't it say on the first page, that for compound sentences with the first part of the sentence in the past, the only possible tense for the second part is the imparfait?

Comment: I don't know what it says on the first page because for some reason, I can't access this site. Anyway, please edit your question and add all required information. We shouldn't rely on an external site where the information might evolve, disappear.

Comment: @jlliagre I added the picture, can you see it now?

Answer (score 9):

I think your sentence needs a little context. As it stands, one could convey it by either

> I knew I should have gone (there) => Je savais que j'aurais dû y aller

or

> Je savais que j'aurais dû partir

I knew (past simple) can be conveyed by j'ai su (passé composé), je savais (imparfait), je sus (literature; passé simple)

**EDIT**

When expressing moral obligation/regrets/criticism/reproach, the English ‘should have’ is translated by the past
conditional of devoir + infinitive, not by a compound tense of the main verb as in English:

> Tu aurais dû me le dire = You should have told me.

> Je t'avais dit que tu aurais dû venir plus tôt.

See the question: [Would have, should have, must have](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17370/would-have-should-have-must-have)

Also
http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/grammar/translation_should.shtml

Regarding the table you are talking about see the reply of user @ruakh. Personally, I would use the following link: http://www.aidenet.eu/conjugaison50.htm instead.

> L'ASPECT, faut-il le rappeler, exprime la façon dont est présenté le
> déroulement ou l'accomplissement d'une action. Cette action peut être
> présentée comme en cours de réalisation (fait NON ACCOMPLI = formes
> simples) ou déjà terminée (fait ACCOMPLI = formes composées avec les
> auxiliaires "avoir ou être").
>
> - Il conduit, il conduisait, il conduira la voiture > NON-ACCOMPLI.
> - Il a, il avait, il aura conduit la voiture > ACCOMPLI.
>   ?
>   (...)
>   mode  Le verbe de la subordonnée est à l'un des modes suivants : INDICATIF si >l'action est réelle, SUBJONCTIF si l'action est incertaine ou CONDITIONNEL si >l'action est soumise à condition.
>
> Le verbe de la subordonnée correspond à un temps qui est fonction du moment où >l'action se passe et en rapport avec les autres actions de la phrase :
>
> - Je crois qu'il pleut (maintenant = simultanéité).
> - Je crois qu'il pleuvra (demain = postériorité).
> - Je crois qu'il pleuvait (hier = antériorité).
>
> (...)
> Si le verbe de la proposition principale se trouve au passé, le verbe de la >subordonnée se met selon le sens aux temps suivants.

> Imparfait ou passé simple si le fait est simultané :
>
> - J'ai cru (ind. PC) qu'il chantait (ind. imparfait) à notre arrivée.
> - Il nous salua (ind. PS) dès qu'il entra (ind. PS).

> Futur du passé ou futur antérieur si le temps est postérieur :
>
> - J'ai pensé (ind. PC) qu'elle chanterait (cond. futur) demain.
> - J'ai pensé (ind. PC) qu'elle aurait chanté (cond. futur antérieur) avant-hier.

> Plus-que-parfait ou passé antérieur si le fait est antérieur :
>
> - J'ai cru (ind.PC) qu'il avait chanté (ind. PQP) hier.
> - Il chanta (ind. PS) dès qu'il eut obtenu (ind. passé antérieur) le silence.
>
> *** Si une action se passe PENDANT qu'une autre a lieu (c'est-à-dire ni avant, >ni après) alors on utilise le couple imparfait / passé simple
> L'imparfait exprime une action dans la durée : Je regardais la télévision...
> Le passé simple exprime une action soudaine : ... lorsque Pierre entra dans la >pièce.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, but also, the table you refer to is largely correct. It's just that *devoir* is a special case, in that it has a special meaning in the conditional; « je devrais y aller », despite using the conditional mood, can have a present-tense sense, as it does in your example.

So:

- « Je dois y aller » → « Je savais que je devais y aller »
- « Je devrais y aller » → « Je savais que j’aurais dû y aller »

(That said, despite my statement that the table is largely correct, I'm not sure that it's actually the best or most helpful way to structure the information it's trying to present.)